# Is this pc build a good fast low cost blender internal render solution?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I will not use cycles, so I'm using only CPU. so, is this a fast render build on my new PC with windows 64 bit?

Specifications:

- AMD razer 7 1700x processor
- Asus prime b350-plus motherboard
- 64 GB RAM memory

Comment: Hardware questions are considered off topic here. Try Blender artist forum instead

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is hardware related

Comment: Also have in mind that Blender internal render is deprecated and is being phased out. 2.79 should be the last major version including it, 2.8 onwards should no longer include it

Comment: ok. sorry, i didnt knew that internal render was going to disscontinue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with AMD CPUs (thought they were just graphics), but if you've got 64GB of RAM, chances are your computer is no slouch. I'm using a 2013 MacBook Pro laptop with a 2.3GHz Intel Core i7 (and 16GB of RAM), and it works fine for Cycles. I'd give it a try, and if it doesn't work, no harm done!

Also, you don't need a GPU at all for Cycles, and getting it to work can actually be quite difficult.

Comment: ok. im getting 32 gb ram. 64 was too expensive.

Comment: I'll bet! (: I've never really had a problem with RAM in Blender, except when working with an absurdly heavy scene where the file _on disk_ was ~500MB.

Comment: As for how fast it'll be, that will depend on your scene, of course, as well as how much noise you're willing to put up with. (Using my GPU actually seemed to be _slower_ than using the CPU, but I haven't conducted any sort of decent testing.)

Comment: ok. my dad ordered this pc build today to me:

Comment: ￼
ASUS Prime B350-Plus, Socket-AM4                                                      
￼
AMD Ryzen 7 1700X Prosessor                 
￼
Corsair Hydro Series H60 CPU cooler                      
                             ￼
Cooler Master G650M, 650W PSU
                                                      
￼
ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1070 8GB Mini            
                                           ￼
Crucial Ballistix Sport LT DDR4 32GB
                                                     ￼
Corsair Carbide 88R Midi Tower Sort
￼
Kingston A400 480GB 2.5" SSD￼
TP-Link Archer T9E AC1900 PCI Express

Comment: 8GB on a _graphics card_!? Wow. Spiffy setup! (: